# Training data has more columns than test data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, training-data

I have training data with 16 columns and test data with 14columns and the last two target columns from training data is not present in test data(which is very important). Also the test data is already given and training data is also given. 
The approach i was thinking is to start off by combining the train and test data and then split the data as `X_Train`, `Y_Train`, `X_Test` and `Y_Test`. Is it a good way to do or is there any other way to start off?

I haven't coded for it yet. But before i could do i need some advice to start it.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you combine and split them again if you already have your training and testing set given?

Comment: I'm afraid i don't have test target columns and if i use knn, i need to specify target column for test data right?

Comment: As is, question has nothing to do with `python` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know what task you want to solve, but it seems like you want to train a model on your training dataset and then predict the targets of your test dataset (that's why you don't have those).

If you want to evaluate how good your model is doing in the training phase you can split your training data into a real training set and a validation set with `test_train_split(X_train,y_train)`. If the validation accuracy is good enough you take your trained model and call `model.predict(X_test)` on it

Comment: Yes, i did the same. I was wondering how to use X_test coz i already get X_test from the train_test split, so when should i use the new test data? I got a good score of 0.90 percent and then i am not sure how i should use the new test data?

Answer (score 1):

For evaluating your model you could just split your training set into training and testing ( using 20% for testing ) and use cross validation.

Your test set is useless for evaluation if it doesn't contain target variable. I'm thinking that this is an assignment or a competition ur taking ? Because they always give you a test set with keeping the targets for themselves for evaluating you

Comment: Yes, You are right. What i did is train and test split on training data. Then i tested on same training data and gives me a good score. I am not sure how i should be using the new test data to predict new columns.

Comment: @KSp You can not use new test data to evaluate your model.If you are confident enough that your model is trained well, then your model should ideally work good on new test data as well.If you are doing it for  some online hackathon , then your leader-board score will reflect the model actual performance. Otherwise, you can use your data/business knowledge to judge the final results.

Comment: I need to predict those target columns of test data. So i can't stop with what i did so far. I predicted on the X_test as of now and get a score of 0.91 and i need an idea of how to use the test data which i have to fill those target columns.

Comment: Okay! Anyway i got an idea :) So i will try it.